# How do you do reading from a file and then split that file into multiple files with Clojure?

Tags: ruby, file, functional-programming, clojure

I have a text file, that need to be split in the following way: first line is an identifier and must be at the top of every file created, following lines are a pair of digits separated by a comma:

Example

> 12345
> 12000,2
> 13000,5
> 12501,1
> etc...

When the script runs it leaves 3 files in the following way

> p1.dat 12345 12000,2 etc...

> p2.dat 12345 13000,5 etc...

> p3.dat 12345 12501,1 etc...

I have done a *script* that do this  in **Ruby**, but I'm rusted in **Clojure** and/or maybe never learn it properly, could someone give some enlightenment, please?. How could this be done in a 'functional' way?

The Ruby code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
if ARGV.length < 1
  puts """To use this script give the path to the file and the number of parts to divide,
 if you dont give this number 2 is assumed"""
  exit
end

file_path = ARGV[0].to_s

if ARGV.length == 1
  n_parts = 2
else
  n_parts = ARGV[1].to_i
end

particiones = Array.new(n_parts)
j = Array(1..n_parts)

File.readlines(file_path).each_with_index do |linea, i|
  #first line is id, so it must be in every divided part
  if i == 0 #repeat first line in every file
    j.each do |particion|
      particiones[particion-1] = linea
    end
    next # After processing first line
  end
  particiones[(i-1)%n_partes] +=  linea # parts get stored
end

j.each do |particion| # files are written
  # Crear los archivos p1, p2,... etc
  File.open("p"+particion.to_s+".dat", 'w'){|f| f << particiones[particion-1]}
  puts "File p"+particion.to_s+".dat was created"
end
```

Comment: I think this question might be a better fit at Code Review:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Please write a program for me" is not a good fit for Code Review either.

Comment: It's not write code for me, seriously I tried to work on it, but the code in Clojure is so early stage(it's not working) that just couldn't post it. The thing is I'm not so able in Clojure to get something working, and I don't see a clear way as how could be done, the only thing that surely will work is use Java arrays but I just don't see as a good functional way to do it.

Comment: Another options that crossed my mind before were to use *take-nth* and convert to *sets* to do a difference but the order get messed in the conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your task correctly- try this:

Code:

```
(defn split-file
  "First argument is path to file,
  second argument is number of created files, default is 2"
  ([path] (split-file path 2))
  ([path parts]
   (let [numbers (-> (slurp path)
                     (clojure.string/replace #"\n|\r\n" " ")
                     (clojure.string/split #" "))
         identifier (first numbers)
         pairs (rest numbers)
         file-names (for [i (range 1 (inc parts))]
                      (str "p" i ".dat"))
         data-for-files (->> (iterate rest pairs)
                             (take parts)
                             (map #(take-nth parts %))
                             (map #(conj % identifier))
                             (map #(clojure.string/join "\n" %)))]
     (doall (map (fn [file-name text]
                   (spit file-name text))
                 file-names
                 data-for-files)))))
```

Call:

```
(split-file "data.txt" 3)
```

(it returns `(nil nil nil)`, but that doesn't matter)

File `data.txt`:

```
12345
12000,2
13000,5
12501,1
12000,2
13000,5
12501,1
12000,2
13000,5
12501,1
```

Output files:

`p1.dat`:

```
12345
12000,2
12000,2
12000,2
```

`p2.dat`:

```
12345
13000,5
13000,5
13000,5
```

`p3.dat`:

```
12345
12501,1
12501,1
12501,1
```